# liquibase tagExist command exit code

Tags: liquibase

i am using liquibase 3.4.1 in the command line way.
My command looks like this :

```
D:\Work>java -cp ".\*" liquibase.integration.commandline.Main --defaultsFile=liquibase_methods.properties tagExists 4.5
```

works pretty well :

```
The tag 4.5 does not exist in user@jdbc:oracle:thin:@url:port:SID

Liquibase 'tagExists' Successful
```

when I do `echo %errorlevel%`, the OS tells me 0, like the previous command was correcctly released.

is there a 'quite easy' way to get an exit code != 0 when the tagExists command returns that the tag doesn't exist ?

by 'quite easy' I mean also something more proper than parse the result text and look for keywords..

Regards,
Guillaume

Answer (score 1):

This would require a change in the liquibase source code. Looking at the class [src/main/java/liquibase/integration/commandline/Main.java](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/integration/commandline/Main.java#L182-L192) you can see that whether there is an error or not, liquibase just does a `return`. This would need to be changed so that it did `System.exit(int)` and the system would need to be altered so that the commands themselves returned some sort of success code.

I think [Nathan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45756/nathan-voxland) is working on improvements for 4.0, but for the 3.x line it seems like a fairly straightforward change. The issue with a change like this though is what unintended consequences it would have on other systems. I would suggest forking the project on github and making the change for yourself, and then creating a pull request to see if it can be added to the main line code.